# Changing a sub string's forecolor in a datagridview at asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I want to change a **sub string forecolor** in my **gridview**.

I tried something like this:

```
   TaskGridView.Rows[i]
               .Cells[j + 2]
               .Text.Substring(firstInd, length)
               .ForeColor =System.Drawing.Color.DarkSalmon;
```

but there is no **ForeColor** attributes at **String Class**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add the html to your string yourself, via a `span` and a `style` tag
eg:

```
TaskGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j + 2].Text =     
    TaskGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j + 2].Text.Substring(0,firstInd) + 
    "<span style=\"color:salmon\">" + 
    TaskGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j + 2].Text.Substring(firstInd, length) + 
    "</span>"
```